# Phantomjs execute script in background?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm trying to launch a phantomjs script

```
var system = require('system');
var args = system.args;
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open(args[1], function(status) {
  console.log("Status: " + status);
  if(status === "success") {
     var output = page.content();
     console.log(output);
  }
  phantom.exit();
});
```

in follow way:

```
phantomjs test.js <url>
```

I don't understand why if i launch this script on my mac it return console output in the right way (html like as string of the url passed like as argument), but if i launch the same script on another mac, i don't see the console output, but it seems that run process in background; i see on console this output:

```
[1] 19404
[2] 19405
```

but not the html like as string.

Why?
Maybe can be a phantomjs configuration problem?

Comment: Mac is borked? Try linux. This is almost certainly not a PhantomJS issue.

Comment: Artjom are you serious???

Comment: *are you serious???* - yes, with the second half of my comment.

Comment: Btw, `page.content` is a read-only property and not a function, so you should remove the `()`

Comment: Thank you @ArtjomB. Now you right!